# Streamlit input_text: remove tooltip

Tags: streamlit

I am in the process of developing a web app using Streamlit and I am using `text_input` function, and I am facing the following problem:

When I am trying to input some data to the input text it always shows a grey tip "Press enter to apply".
I added the below js code to prevent any action if the user presses enter by mistake since i will be using a submit button:

```py
js_code = """
<script>
document.querySelector('.stTextInput').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is the Enter key
            e.preventDefault();
}
});
</script>
"""

st.markdown(js_code, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

If anyone can help me to remove this tip, so the user will not press enter or lose his time on a useless activity, this will most appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using st.form? If you want to stop widgets from causing an update when they are changed, you can put them in a form which will prevent the newly entered data from being sent to the backend until it is submitted. https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form

Comment: @MathCatsAnd im new to streamlit and im using code on the go, ill try your recommendation. thanks a lot for your support

Comment: @MathCatsAnd thank you a lot for your recommendation, it works fine, any tips regarding how to center the submit button in a form?

Answer (score 0):

As [MathCatsAnd suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783146/streamlit-input-text-issue#comment133682925_75783146), you can use [`st.forms`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783146/streamlit-input-text-issue#comment133682925_75783146). It gives:

```py
import streamlit as st

with st.form("formid"):
    text = st.text_input("Write some text:")

    # Columns to center the Submit button
    cols = st.columns(7)
    with cols[3]:
        submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
        
    if submitted:
        st.write(f"Text: {text}")
```

[image: Form for text with centered submit button]

In order to center the "Submit" button, you can use `st.columns` and write in the middle one (`cols[3]`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    hide_menu_style = """
        <style>
        [data-testid="InputInstructions"] { display:None }
        </style>
        """
    st.markdown(hide_menu_style, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```